# Close dialog blank in iOS app for unprivileged users

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, close-dialog

When selecting the "Close" option in the iOS app, the dialog pops up but is blank for low rep users. The dialog shouldn't exist in the first place for them, since their access is through the "Flag" menu.

> [image: menu choices]
>
> [image: blank dialog]

Comment: I'm taking a look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were missing a check here that would display the close option for everyone.

This should be **fixed in version 0.1.28.**