# Voting to close on a question you already voted on results in a blank dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, ios-app

This is similar to [Close dialog blank in iOS app for unprivileged users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226331/close-dialog-blank-in-ios-app-for-unprivileged-users) but for privileged users.

When voting to close a question you *already* voted on you are presented with the same blank dialog.

To reproduce: vote to close a post. Then vote to close again.

Version 0.1.28.

Comment: 0.1.28?! Wow, they're fast! (going to try and repro)

Comment: I have a fix in the works, but I'm waiting on some API fix before I can mark this as fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in **version 0.1.29**. We will now show an alert that tells you there aren't any flags/reasons for you to select (copy will depend on the situation):

[image]

When you tap OK, thescreen will be dismissed.

In order to prevent this in the first place, I wish we could disable the "close" option immediately after closing a question, but it's not feasible at the moment. (The option goes away if you refresh the question). So, for now, this screen is a possible path.

Comment: Confirmed fixed on 0.1.29.