# iOS app should tell me I've already voted to close, and allow retraction

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, ios-app

Further to [Voting to close on a question you already voted on results in a blank dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226471), the iOS app's interface for "already voted to close" could still be better.

[image]

This isn't a super-helpful dialog. It's not really a "problem", it's an expected result of the fact that I've already cast a close vote.

The app should tell me exactly what's going on: I've already voted to close, and thus cannot vote again.

Of equal importance, it should also allow me to retract my close vote. Before retracting, the app should warn me that no other close action can later be taken. If I attempt to close vote again, the app should tell me that I've already voted to close and retracted that vote, and that I should raise a flag if something still needs to be done.

Comment: Not sure if retraction is supported by the API; does that need a separate request?

Comment: I got this problem myself - not a SE quality experience IMHO. +1 to fix it. The error message should be changed at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

> The app should tell me exactly what's going on: I've already voted to close, and thus cannot vote again

Just for the record, this part of your [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) has already been realized (sort of); the message has been changed:

[image: You may have already voted to close this question or it may have been closed by other users.]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this. The app should also show what votes are cast. Once I vote to close, I can no longer see what other votes are being cast, or how many were cast.

Comment: Development on the iOS and Android apps is currently in hiatus.