# iOS App should indicate whether I already flagged a post

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, ios-app

When walking through new questions and answers, there are always some off-topic and low-quality posts, which I want to flag as such. However with increasing number of posts it is hard to remember which ones I already flagged.

So, I would appreciate an indicator in the iOS App that shows me whether or not I have already flagged a post (in the standard thread view, that is, viewing a certain question and its answers).

I see the following possibilities for that:

- a number at the *Flag* link should indicate how many flags I put (similar to the *Edit* link when I suggested an edit, it changes to *Edit (1)*);
- the *Flag* link could be highlighted as soon as I set at least one flag (similar to the *Favorite* link which becomes bright yellow when I selected the related question as one of my favourites);
- even both of the above;

In addition, the votes dialog appearing when following the *Flag* link should disable and grey out the votes I already did, like in the web version. (If I got it right, this might be at least partially covered by this feature request: [iOS app should tell me I've already voted to close, and allow retraction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229711/300036).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that's not currently in the web version of SE and was declined here: [When you flag a post, can the 'Flag' button be highlighted or something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37147/when-you-flag-a-post-can-the-flag-button-be-highlighted-or-something/)  The same reasoning stands for the app.

That said, I will be greying out already selected flags starting in 1.4.3.3, so this is half [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) half [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

> [image: Screenshot showing greyed out flag options]